# Networking failed to start and mouse also not working

Tags: networking, mouse

I have installed ISPCONFIG SERVER ON UBUNTU 12.04 DESKTOP.
On update my mouse stopped working.
Then I run a command

```
sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade.
```

It took lot of time to reconfigure, after I restarted the system, now mouse is still not working and I am faced with another problem. My networking fails to start.
I am also getting this error on start

```
modprobe:fatal : could not load /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/modules - No such file or directory.
```

Need a solution on this as I am really stuck and my server is as good as down without networking
Thanks.

Comment: Now that you have found the answer please mark the question as answered(by accepting the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution somewhere, which I am putting here for reference and help for someone.

To fix this you have to reboot with another kernel version or reinstall the needed kernel package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0--generic
```

So I have rebooted with previous kernel, where networking was working, but not the mouse, but after running the above command and reboot everything is working fine.